# Unity: Photon NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

I'm new with Unity and Photon. I'm developing a game for my school assignment. When I run my game 2 times at the same time. I got this errors. One of players' objects references are none. First one is matching but second one is not matching and That's why I can not run 2 different game at the same time. Could you explain how can I fix this error ? I've some pictures about errors and Inspectors. I'm instantiating my player OnJoinedRoom method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezqiz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwGiV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a0Ml.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9h8l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYA5.png)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The real problem why the first clone is okay but when second one created, I got NullPointerException?